# Workbench section not showing in apache jmeter

Tags: java, apache, jmeter, workbench, jmeter-4.0

I am new to jmeter. I successfully installed jmeter into my windows machine. I opened "**jmeter.bat**" under **apache-jmeter-4.0\bin**. But the jmeter window is not showing the workbench section in the left panel. I have attached the screenshot below in the **ApacheJmeter**.

[image: ApacheJmeter]

Comment: It is drop from new UI
You can use Test plan as your work bench

Answer (score 73, accepted):

It's not a bug but a [feature](http://jmeter.apache.org/changes.html) since JMeter 4:

> Workbench has been dropped from UI, you can now use Non Test Elements as immediate children of Test Plan.

You can now use elements in Test Plan as you used previously in Workbench

You can see also an [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44746278/why-workbench-is-shown-as-default-in-jmeter) that asked why workbench is shown in the first place
[image]

Comment: in JMeter 4 you don't need it, It's not advised, but you can still use JMeter 3.3

Comment: @user7294900 Unfortunately, workbench is still mentioned in the official tutorial: http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf

Comment: @matandked yes, it's a very old documentation, you can open enhancement for JMeter http://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi?product=JMeter

Answer (score 10):

You can find all features of Workbench here:

[image]

Navigate to Test Plan -> Add --> Non-test Elements, now you could see all required features of Workbench

Comment: The other answer is fine, but this one actually helps solve the problem. Thanks!