# Jmeter proxy setup issue

Tags: testing, jmeter, jmeter-4.0

I was trying to enable recordings in JMeter. For that, I was following this document: http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf

I couldn't find workbench option in my JMeter as I am using Jmeter 4.0. [image]

So I added HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder to my Test Plan. But couldn't proceed with step 11, as I couldn't find any “URL Patterns to Include”.

Below is my JMeter UI:
[image]

How can I proceed from step 11? Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR** click on Request Filtering tab

[Workbench was dropped in JMeter 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48780603/workbench-section-not-showing-in-apache-jmeter/48780628#48780628) so you can add it under Test plan.

JMeter's [Componenet reference](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) holds the latest updates

- Notice that [JMeter 5](https://jmeter.apache.org/changes.html) also improve the recordering, so it advised to use the latest version:

> Recording feature has been improved to provide a popup that is always on top when you navigate in browser allowing you to name transactions while you navigate in your application.

So regarding step 11, naming has changed to `Patterns to Include`:

> Patterns to Include
> Regular expressions that are matched against the full URL that is sampled. Allows filtering of requests that are recorded. All requests pass through, but only those that meet the requirements of the Include/Exclude fields are recorded. If both Include and Exclude are left

For quick setup use JMeter's Templates which have [Recording template](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html)

> Select Templates… on the menu bar
>
> Select Recording template on the list

[image]